# While loop exceeds max number attempts (3) when asking for an answer

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

In my program it's supposed to ask the user a question and give them 3 chances to guess the correct answer. But my "while" loop seems to give the user a 4th chance to answer the question and bypassing the "max_attempts" variable.

```
print('Quiz program!\n')
answer = input('What is the capital of Wisconsin? ')
attempt = 1
max_attempts = 4

while answer != 'Madison':
    attempt += 1
    print('You got it wrong, please try again.\n')
    answer = input('What is the capital of Wisconsin? ')
    if attempt == max_attempts:
        print('You used the maximum number of attempts, sorry. The correct answer is "Madison"')
        break
else:
    print(f"Correct! Thanks for playing. It took you {attempt} attempt(s).")
```

Comment: Would max_attempts=3 work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your condition. It should be

```
attempt < max_attempts:
```

I also tried implementing it in a more readable way

```
def main():
    introduction()
    attempt=1
    while attemptValid(attempt) and answerIsWrong(askQuestion(), attempt):
        attempt += 1

def attemptValid(attempt):
    max_attempts=4
    if attempt < max_attempts:
        return 1
    print('You used the maximum number of attempts, sorry. The correct answer is "Madison"')
    return 0

def answerIsWrong(answer, attempt):
    if answer != 'Madison':
        return 1
    print(f"Correct! Thanks for playing. It took you {attempt} attempt(s).")
    return 0

def introduction():
    print('Quiz program!\n')

def askQuestion():
    return input('What is the capital of Wisconsin? ')

main()
```

Comment: Forgot to add this line after answer  != 'Madison' in answerIsWrong function
            
    print('You got it wrong, please try again.\n')

Answer (score 2):

All the above answers are correct, just adding a slightly different variant.

```
print('Quiz program!\n')
attempt = 1
max_attempts = 4

while attempt < max_attempts:
   attempt += 1

   answer = input('What is the capital of Wisconsin? ')
   if answer == 'Madison':
      print("Correct!")
      break
   else:
      print('You got it wrong, please try again.\n')

print("Thanks for playing. It took you %s attempt(s)." %(attempt-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `max_attempts = 4` - change that to 3.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the counter attempt `attempt` is equal to `max_attempts` at the beginning of the loop, before you increment the counter again, and you should set `max_attempt` to 3 instead:

```
print('Quiz program!\n')
answer = input('What is the capital of Wisconsin? ')
attempt = 1
max_attempts = 3

while answer != 'Madison':
    if attempt == max_attempts:
        print('You used the maximum number of attempts, sorry. The correct answer is "Madison"')
        break
    attempt += 1
    print('You got it wrong, please try again.\n')
    answer = input('What is the capital of Wisconsin? ')
else:
    print(f"Correct! Thanks for playing. It took you {attempt} attempt(s).")
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely, by adjusting the variable `max_attempts` to 2, 3, 4, 5 you will eventually find the right number to give you the correct behaviour. But I believe it is more important to know how to think of this issue. I would suggest to think in terms of loop invariants: Make up a condition that is always true in the loop and enforce it while you write the loop. In this case, let's make the value of `attempt` and the number of time of `input()` calls equal, and see if your loop is right:

```
print('Quiz program!\n')
answer = input('What is the capital of Wisconsin? ')
attempt = 1
max_attempts = 4
```

So your `attempt` set to 1 after `input()`. This part is OK, and satisfied the invariant (even it is before the loop). Then the loop:

```
while answer != 'Madison':
    attempt += 1
    print('You got it wrong, please try again.\n')
    answer = input('What is the capital of Wisconsin? ')
    if attempt == max_attempts:
        print('You used the maximum number of attempts, sorry. The correct answer is "Madison"')
        break
```

You increment `attempt`, then print, then call `input()`. I will put the `attempt` line right after `input()` call to be consistent with the code above but either case, at right before the `if` statement, we still have value of `attempt` equals to number of times we called `input()`. That is why you have this behaviour.

Now on how to change your code: you now knows what is "invariant" in the loop. You have to decide (1) when to do the check of `attempt == max_attempts` and (2) what is the right value of `max_attempts` to check. Other people's answer already gave you the solution.